# Using QPointer and QObject::connect with C++11

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qpointer

I'm using Qt 5.4 and trying to resume accepting new connections when the "disconnected" signal from my `QTcpSocket` is emitted. So I wrote the following in .h and .cpp file respectively:

```
QPointer<QTcpServer> tcpServer; // in .h file

connect(tcpSocket, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected, [=](){
        tcpServer->resumeAccepting(); // in .cpp file
    });
```

As you can see, I use `QPointer` class for `tcpSocket`. With the above codes, I'm not able to build my program and receive "no matching function for call to ..." error while I don't have any problem in case of defining `tcpSocket` without `QPointer`.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be smarter to do direct connection.

```
 connect(tcpSocket, &QAbstractSocket::disconnected, 
         tcpServer, &QTcpServer::resumeAccepting);
```

Please note that [nextPendingConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#nextPendingConnection) has parent set to `QTcpServer`, so you can also access server by:

```
 auto tcpServer = qobject_cast<QTcpServer *>(sender()->parent());
```

Comment: Dear @Marker R, connecting in that way requires both tcpSocket and tcpServer to be a simple pointer not a Qpointer. so it does not work in this case.

Comment: @thung Thanks for your comment. It works for me. First please write it as an answer to this question for others. Second qt official help says that: "A guarded pointer, QPointer<T>, behaves like a normal C++ pointer T *, except that it is automatically set to 0 when the referenced object is destroyed (unlike normal C++ pointers, which become "dangling pointers" in such cases).", and I have a lot of signal/slot connection which did not use the QPointer::data for them and they are working fine (At least I think :-|). So should I correct them too?

Comment: @Reza Are you sure you didn't use the old connect syntax for the working connections? For example `connect(object, SIGNAL(objectSignal()), object, SLOT(objectSlot()));`

Comment: @thuga Yes, I'm using the old connect syntax 'connect(object, SIGNAL(objectSignal()), object, SLOT(objectSlot()));'. Do you mean Qpointer works with this kind of connecting signal/slot?

Comment: @Reza It appears so, but it doesn't make any sense to me.